# How to make ios app use only 960 x 640 resolution on iPad?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

I have ios game, that is designed for iPod 4, iPhone 4.

I have no graphics for 320 x 460 resolution, but I want my app to be able to launch on iPad.

Is there some way to launch app on iPad at 960 x 640 resolution, at the center of the screen with automatical coordinates conversion?

Note: I use cocos2d.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be more complicated than you may think.

If your app is not a Universal app but only a iPhone/iPod app, it will be 320 * 480 on iPad/iPad 2. On the New iPad, with Retina Display support, the app will be 640 * 960 automatically. Please refer to:

- https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/42978/retina-iphone-app-on-the-new-ipad
- http://www.macrumors.com/2012/03/20/new-ipad-uses-retina-graphics-when-running-iphone-apps/

For jailbroken iPad/iPad 2, there is an app "RetinaPad" available in Cydia Store which enables them to run iPhone app in Retina mode.

A possible solution to your question come to my mind is to:

1. Make your app universal.
2. In `+ (id)scene` method, create a "wrapper" `CCLayer` inside the `CCScene`, and add your own `CCLayer` into the "wrapper" layer instead of the scene.
3. Set `positionInPixel` of your own layer according to the actual resolution of the device by `[[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSizeInPixels]` (possible values are 320*480, 640*960, 768*1024, or 1536*2048).
4. Set `scale` of your own layer to 0.5 if the device is 320*480.

I don't have the requirement in your question so most likely I will not verify this approach... You may have a try if it's really what you want.

Comment: Okay, I'll try it. Seems like it is an appropriate solution for me:)